# Return Cell based off approximate match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A software that I use allows us to export reports directly to Excel. The report I am working with has a row at the bottom that always starts with "Total x". I am trying to create a formula that can get me the value of x returned. I have tried using Vlookup, and have had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a vlookup with a wildcard attached to it.

```
=VLOOKUP(F1&"*",A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Here, F1 has "Total x", and column A has a bunch of values such as "Total x1234" as one of them. This works well as long as you have just one row that starts with "Total x" in column A.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem perfectly